# Are there any known methods to generalize multiple trajectories into one "optimal" path based on energy consumption?

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series, regression, dataset

Say that I have a database with timeseries coordinate data from a vehicle going from A to B multiple times but with slightly varying trajectories each time, leading to different amounts of energy being consumed (this data would also be part of the dataset). Are there any known methods to generalize all these trajectories into one single trajectory where the least amount of energy would be consumed?

My (somewhat limited) knowledge of the field leads me to believe this can be solved as a regression problem where the trained hypothesis function would describe the curve of the optimal trajectory. But I can not really on my own visualize how this would be done in practice, hence the question.